# Send a value to an iframe

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php program that uses a POST value to start it. I want to run the program my other website using an iframe. I have a form linking to the page the runs the iframe using a POST method. I there anyway to get the iframe to read the post rather than it's parent?

Otherwise is there a way to send a value to and iframe using JavaScript that the iframe will read as a POST value?

If neither of these are possible, is there any other way or will I have to create another copy of the program that is suited to start from the iframe.
If I have to do this, is there a way that the iframe can detect the parent page that is running it so that I can disable the program unless the parent is my website to stop people hijacking the link?

Comment: yes you can detect the parent page that is running it so that you can disable the program unless the parent is your website to stop people hijacking the link for live example try to load stackoverflow.com in an iframe

Comment: You can use window.top.location from within the iframe to get the url of the parent page on which your iframe is running

Comment: Thanks Uttara, I'll give that a try over the weekend a see what happens.